# Error converting data type varchar to numeric doing a select to some tables in a linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I did a select statement to some tables that I have in  a linked server

```
SELECT A.[STCOMP], A.[STDATE], A.[STUNM], A.[STQTY], A.[STWWAY], A.[STVOID],
       A.[STMATR], A.[STTCKT], C.[RWDESC], A.[STDESC], A.[STLNDF], B.[CSLNAM],
       B.[CBLNAM],D.[CVAR6]    
FROM [EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[SCTRN] A 
INNER JOIN [EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[CUST] B 
  ON A.[STNCST] = B.[CMSTC#] 
 AND A.[STNCMP]= B.[CMSTCO] 
 AND A.[STCOMP]= B.[CCMPNY] 
 AND A.[STCUST]= B.[CCUST#] 
INNER JOIN [EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[SCRWC] C 
  ON C.[RWDESC]= A.[STRWC] 
 AND C.[RWCOMP]= A.[STCOMP] 
INNER JOIN [EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[CUSX] D 
  ON A.[STCOMP]= D.[CCMPNY] 
 AND A.[STCUST]= D.[CCUST#] 
WHERE A.[STCOMP]='51' 
  AND A.[STDATE] BETWEEN 20140317 AND 20140323 
  AND A.[STVOID] = 'N' 
ORDER BY A.[STTCKT]
```

and I got this error

```
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

Comment: What you have to remember is that you at least have access to your data. We don't. You need to narrow down which column(s) in which table(s) are causing you problems. Then narrow it down to "all rows" or "some rows", and in the latter case, work out *which* rows.

Comment: when I double clic on the error it highlighted all of this fields A.[STCOMP], A.[STDATE],A.[STUNM],A.[STQTY],A.[STWWAY],A.[STVOID],A.[STMATR],A.[STTCKT],C.[RWDESC],A.[STDESC],
A.[STLNDF],B.[CSLNAM],B.[CBLNAM],D.[CVAR6]

Comment: I would guess the error is on one of the joins.  THe nature of the error is that the datatypes between two of the tables is not the same and the system can't do the implicit conversion.  The error is likely in `A.[STNCST] = B.[CMSTC#] ` or `A.[STCUST]= B.[CCUST#]` or `A.[STCUST]= D.[CCUST#] ` but it could be on any of the associations.  For each table we'd need to know the data types of the fields being joined.  I'm going to guess you have some unexpected data in one of them or the table structure was created incorrectly in one of the two tables.

Comment: I found this on one of my joins C.[RWDESC] string 35
A.[STRWC]  number how can I fix it?

Comment: That would depend on the results you want.  Logically a string can't be a number, but a number could be a string. So you could cast STRWC to a string but this will exclude any records in C that have character data as the inner join will eliminate them.  If you need ALL records in both tables, then you have to alter the join to be an outer join.  Now if C table and A table **should** both support character data, I'd alter the table structure to have A.STRWC be varchar(35). But you need to consider the impact of such a change on an existing system.

Comment: the error was mine, the time I wrote the the joins I piked a wrong field because the name in the table is similar between them. Thanks a lot for your help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe that some of the columns that you are using in the joins have different data-type?

For example, take the part " A.[STNCMP] = B.[CMSTCO]"  and say that

- A.[STNCMP] is integer
- B.[CMSTCO] is varchar

Then that B.[CMSTCO] could contain values that are not integer-convertible.

This kind of issue clearly can happen on any column used on any join...

Comment: when I do those links in crystal reports or in access it brings me all the data without any error

Comment: I found this on one of my joins C.[RWDESC] string 35 A.[STRWC] number how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Without the data, i could guess that the field STDATE is varchar? In that case you can try this:

```
select A.[STCOMP], A.[STDATE],A.[STUNM],A.[STQTY],A.[STWWAY],A.[STVOID],A.[STMATR],A.[STTCKT],C.[RWDESC],A.[STDESC],
A.[STLNDF],B.[CSLNAM],B.[CBLNAM],D.[CVAR6]
FROM [EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[SCTRN] A INNER JOIN [EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[CUST] B ON
A.[STNCST] = B.[CMSTC#] AND A.[STNCMP]= B.[CMSTCO] AND A.[STCOMP]= B.[CCMPNY] AND A.[STCUST]= B.[CCUST#] INNER JOIN 
[EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[SCRWC] C ON C.[RWDESC]= A.[STRWC] AND C.[RWCOMP]= A.[STCOMP] INNER JOIN 
[EPAK].[B00BF4CR].[IWSE4S8].[CUSX] D ON A.[STCOMP]= D.[CCMPNY] AND A.[STCUST]= D.[CCUST#] WHERE 
A.[STCOMP]='51' AND A.[STDATE] BETWEEN '20140317' AND '20140323' AND A.[STVOID] = 'N' ORDER BY A.[STTCKT]
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Edit your original post to include table structure and some rows of data.

Comment: due to my low reputation I cannot include any image or something like that